# XML to DropDownList

Tags: xpath, html.dropdownlistfor

// I have the following XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <warehouse>
          <cat id="computer">
            <item>
              <SN>1</SN>
              <name>Toshiba</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
              <price>400 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>2</SN>
              <name>Dell</name>
              <quantity>14</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
              <price>300 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>3</SN>
              <name>Dell</name>
              <quantity>14</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
              <price>300 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>5</SN>
              <name>Dell</name>
              <quantity>14</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
              <price>300 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>6</SN>
              <name>Dell</name>
              <quantity>14</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
              <price>300 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>8</SN>
              <name>Toshiba</name>
              <quantity>13</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 5 GB HD: 512 GB3</description>
              <price>400 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>9</SN>
              <name>Toshiba</name>
              <quantity>13</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 5 GB HD: 512 GB3</description>
              <price>400 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>dsfdSF</SN>
              <name>fsdfsD</name>
              <quantity>dsfdSFS</quantity>
              <description>FSDFS</description>
              <price>FSDFSD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>dsfdSF</SN>
              <name>fsdfsD</name>
              <quantity>dsfdSFS</quantity>
              <description>FSDFS</description>
              <price>FSDFSD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>alia</SN>
              <name>alia</name>
              <quantity>alia</quantity>
              <description>alia</description>
              <price>alia</price>
            </item>
          </cat>
          <cat id="Stationery">
            <item>
              <SN> 1 </SN>
              <name>note books</name>
              <quantity>250</quantity>
              <description>Caterpiller</description>
              <price>5 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN> 2 </SN>
              <name> pencils </name>
              <quantity> 300 </quantity>
              <description> Caterpiller </description>
              <price> 2 USD </price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN> 3 </SN>
              <name> note books </name>
              <quantity> 250 </quantity>
              <description> Caterpiller  </description>
              <price> 5 USD </price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>4</SN>
              <name>pencils</name>
              <quantity>45</quantity>
              <description>Pilot</description>
              <price>4 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>5</SN>
              <name>pencils</name>
              <quantity>45</quantity>
              <description>Pilot</description>
              <price>4 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>6</SN>
              <name>pencils</name>
              <quantity>45</quantity>
              <description>Pilot</description>
              <price>4 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>7</SN>
              <name>sdfsdfsdfsdfsd</name>
              <quantity>sdfsdf</quantity>
              <description>dsfsdfs</description>
              <price>sdfsdf</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>8</SN>
              <name>pencils</name>
              <quantity>45</quantity>
              <description>Pilot</description>
              <price>4 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>9</SN>
              <name>books</name>
              <quantity>250</quantity>
              <description>chinses</description>
              <price>3 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>alia</SN>
              <name>alia</name>
              <quantity>alia</quantity>
              <description>alia</description>
              <price>alia</price>
            </item>
          </cat>
          <cat id="Furniture">
            <item>
              <SN> 1 </SN>
              <name>dasd</name>
              <quantity>asdasd</quantity>
              <description>das</description>
              <price>dasd</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN> 2 </SN>
              <name> chairs </name>
              <quantity> 18 </quantity>
              <description> European Type</description>
              <price> 150 USD </price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>3</SN>
              <name>Tabels</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>European Type</description>
              <price>50 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>4</SN>
              <name>Tabels</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>European Type</description>
              <price>50 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>5</SN>
              <name>Tabels</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>European Type</description>
              <price>50 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>6</SN>
              <name>Tabels</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>European Type</description>
              <price>50 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>7</SN>
              <name>Tabels</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>European Type</description>
              <price>50 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>8</SN>
              <name>Tabels</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>European Type</description>
              <price>50 USD</price>
            </item>
            <item>
              <SN>alia</SN>
              <name>alia</name>
              <quantity>alia</quantity>
              <description>alia</description>
              <price>alia</price>
            </item>
          </cat>
        </warehouse>
```

I want to create using ASP.net a Drop Down List to display the contents of  where .
    I have tried this x path expression

```
warehouse/cat[@id='computer']/item/SN/text()
```

but it dose not work and the Drop Down List still empty!! help me please.*/

or how can i solve my problem using this code on pagerloader

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(MapPath("~/XML/XML.xml"));
            DataView dm = ds.Tables["cat"].DefaultView;
            DataView dv = ds.Tables["item"].DefaultView;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SN";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SN";


            //now bind the dropdownlist to the dataview
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dv;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

        }
```

i just want to add attribute.

Comment: You don't have to `comment` your description here, there's no need to use `//` or `/* */` to display regular text. And for code, you have to indent it by 4 spaces to be visible as code block. For more info on how to corrently style your questions, read [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Also the xpath seems to be working correctly, can we get the code where you're trying to display the results?

Comment: the code is just a simple web form .  i just want to pass <sn> values into the dropdown list

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" DataTextField="id" DataValueField="id">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/XML/XML.xml" XPath="warehouse/cat[@id='computer']/item/SN/text()"></asp:XmlDataSource>

Comment: or how can solve my problem using this code

if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(MapPath("~/XML/XML.xml"));
            DataView dm = ds.Tables["cat"].DefaultView;
            DataView dv = ds.Tables["item"].DefaultView;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SN";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SN";


            //now bind the dropdownlist to the dataview
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dv;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

        }

Comment: Please add relevant code into your post, instead of in comments. As you can see it's quite unreadable. Also, comments are considered "second-rate citizens" on Stack Overflow, and may be deleted at any time. After editing your post, you can delete these comments yourself.

Comment: i re-edited the main topic

Comment: please check this one , i'm in middle of something and i really need some help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643225/creating-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I was able to get this work, that is if you don't mind changing to use XmlDocument instead of DataSet. The "InnerText" bit isn't ideal, but it beats having to loop through the nodes and binding individually.

*note that I changed the Xpath slightly in order to allow for InnerText as a property to work*

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"~/XML/XML.xml");
            var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("warehouse/cat[@id='computer']/item/SN");

            myDropDown.DataTextField = "InnerText";
            myDropDown.DataValueField = "InnerText";


            //now bind the dropdownlist to the dataview
            myDropDown.DataSource = nodes;
            myDropDown.DataBind();
```