# creating DropdownList

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, html.dropdownlistfor

Consider the following XML file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <warehouse>
              <cat id="computer">
                <item>
                  <SN>1</SN>
                  <name>Toshiba</name>
                  <quantity>12</quantity>
                  <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
                  <price>400 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>2</SN>
                  <name>Dell</name>
                  <quantity>14</quantity>
                  <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
                  <price>300 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>3</SN>
                  <name>Dell</name>
                  <quantity>14</quantity>
                  <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
                  <price>300 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>5</SN>
                  <name>Dell</name>
                  <quantity>14</quantity>
                  <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
                  <price>300 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>6</SN>
                  <name>Dell</name>
                  <quantity>14</quantity>
                  <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
                  <price>300 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>8</SN>
                  <name>Toshiba</name>
                  <quantity>13</quantity>
                  <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 5 GB HD: 512 GB3</description>
                  <price>400 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>9</SN>
                  <name>Toshiba</name>
                  <quantity>13</quantity>
                  <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 5 GB HD: 512 GB3</description>
                  <price>400 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>dsfdSF</SN>
                  <name>fsdfsD</name>
                  <quantity>dsfdSFS</quantity>
                  <description>FSDFS</description>
                  <price>FSDFSD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>dsfdSF</SN>
                  <name>fsdfsD</name>
                  <quantity>dsfdSFS</quantity>
                  <description>FSDFS</description>
                  <price>FSDFSD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>alia</SN>
                  <name>alia</name>
                  <quantity>alia</quantity>
                  <description>alia</description>
                  <price>alia</price>
                </item>
              </cat>
              <cat id="Stationery">
                <item>
                  <SN> 1 </SN>
                  <name>note books</name>
                  <quantity>250</quantity>
                  <description>Caterpiller</description>
                  <price>5 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN> 2 </SN>
                  <name> pencils </name>
                  <quantity> 300 </quantity>
                  <description> Caterpiller </description>
                  <price> 2 USD </price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN> 3 </SN>
                  <name> note books </name>
                  <quantity> 250 </quantity>
                  <description> Caterpiller  </description>
                  <price> 5 USD </price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>4</SN>
                  <name>pencils</name>
                  <quantity>45</quantity>
                  <description>Pilot</description>
                  <price>4 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>5</SN>
                  <name>pencils</name>
                  <quantity>45</quantity>
                  <description>Pilot</description>
                  <price>4 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>6</SN>
                  <name>pencils</name>
                  <quantity>45</quantity>
                  <description>Pilot</description>
                  <price>4 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>7</SN>
                  <name>sdfsdfsdfsdfsd</name>
                  <quantity>sdfsdf</quantity>
                  <description>dsfsdfs</description>
                  <price>sdfsdf</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>8</SN>
                  <name>pencils</name>
                  <quantity>45</quantity>
                  <description>Pilot</description>
                  <price>4 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>9</SN>
                  <name>books</name>
                  <quantity>250</quantity>
                  <description>chinses</description>
                  <price>3 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>alia</SN>
                  <name>alia</name>
                  <quantity>alia</quantity>
                  <description>alia</description>
                  <price>alia</price>
                </item>
              </cat>
              <cat id="Furniture">
                <item>
                  <SN> 1 </SN>
                  <name>dasd</name>
                  <quantity>asdasd</quantity>
                  <description>das</description>
                  <price>dasd</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN> 2 </SN>
                  <name> chairs </name>
                  <quantity> 18 </quantity>
                  <description> European Type</description>
                  <price> 150 USD </price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>3</SN>
                  <name>Tabels</name>
                  <quantity>12</quantity>
                  <description>European Type</description>
                  <price>50 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>4</SN>
                  <name>Tabels</name>
                  <quantity>12</quantity>
                  <description>European Type</description>
                  <price>50 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>5</SN>
                  <name>Tabels</name>
                  <quantity>12</quantity>
                  <description>European Type</description>
                  <price>50 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>6</SN>
                  <name>Tabels</name>
                  <quantity>12</quantity>
                  <description>European Type</description>
                  <price>50 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>7</SN>
                  <name>Tabels</name>
                  <quantity>12</quantity>
                  <description>European Type</description>
                  <price>50 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>8</SN>
                  <name>Tabels</name>
                  <quantity>12</quantity>
                  <description>European Type</description>
                  <price>50 USD</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <SN>alia</SN>
                  <name>alia</name>
                  <quantity>alia</quantity>
                  <description>alia</description>
                  <price>alia</price>
                </item>
              </cat>
            </warehouse>
```

I need to create a drop down list. The drop down list has to display all the values of `<SN>` where `<cat id="computer">` only. 
How can this be done using LINQ or DataView or  Xpath?

Comment: Could you explain better what do you mean for _all the values of where only_?

Comment: i want to make A Drop Down List that display the values of <SN> element under the parent element <cat id="computer"> .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"~/XML/XML.xml");
        var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("warehouse/cat[@id='computer']/item/SN");

        myDropDown.DataTextField = "InnerText";
        myDropDown.DataValueField = "InnerText";


        //now bind the dropdownlist to the dataview
        myDropDown.DataSource = nodes;
        myDropDown.DataBind();
```

Comment: according to this code ,do you know how can i pass dropdwonlist.text into @id instead of the @id='computer' ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. You want the dropdownlist to redefine itself based on what its selected text is?

Answer (score 0):

Load the xml into an XElement:

```
        var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
```

Execute XPath to select the SN elements in the cats with id computer: (+ put them in a list)

```
        var snValues = xml.XPathSelectElements("//cat[@id='computer']/item/SN")
                        .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Required usings:

```
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Xml.Linq;
        using System.Xml.XPath;
```